# Combining the Endfloat package and an appendix with different figure numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, appendices, endfloat

I've been struggling with this issue a while, and I've looked at several other related questions on here to no avail.

I'm submitting an article to a journal using the elsarticle class file, and figures, tables, figure/table lists must be provided at the end of the text. Normally the endfloat package would be perfect for this, however I have an appendices environment at the end, including figures labelled A.1, A.2, etc. When I use endfloat, the A. prefix to the appendix figures is removed and they are relabelled to follow the figure list in the main text.

Essentially I need endfloat to behave as normal, but to list the appendix figures with my preferred figure numbers/letters rather than tacking them on as Fig. 13, 14 etc. Is this doable?

Basic working example below, with endfloat enabled and causing trouble:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
    \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}

\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1cm} }

\begin{document}

\LipsumPar{1}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
A FIGURE
\caption{First  figure}
\end{figure}

\LipsumPar{2}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
ANOTHER FIGURE
\caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{CCCCCCC} \toprule
1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\label{table}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\appendixpage

\section{Appendix A}
\label{Appendix A}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
APPENDIX FIGURE
\caption{Appendix figure 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
ANOTHER APPENDIX FIGURE
\caption{Appendix figure 2}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The redefinition of \thefigure is lost when the appendices environment ends.  You could put it into each figure (when used) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `\addtodelayedfloat{figure}{...}` to add commands to the fff file before the next figure.

```
\documentclass[authoryear,review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
    \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}

\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1cm} }

\begin{document}

\LipsumPar{1}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
A FIGURE
\caption{First  figure}
\end{figure}

\LipsumPar{2}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
ANOTHER FIGURE
\caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{CCCCCCC} \toprule
1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\label{table}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{appendices}
\addtodelayedfloat{figure}{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}%
  \setcounter{figure}{0}}%

\appendixpage

\section{Appendix A}
\label{Appendix A}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
APPENDIX FIGURE
\caption{Appendix figure 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
ANOTHER APPENDIX FIGURE
\caption{Appendix figure 2}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is simple and solves the problem perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The suggest solution works only when there are no markers. However, if you activate markers, they say [Insert figure 3 about here] instead of [insert figure A1 about here]